# My code returns a StackOverFlowException when I enter a name... I don't understand why

Tags: c#, oop, events, delegates

My code's purpose is to change my 'dispatcher' object's name and whilst this is done through the dispatcher's name property's setter, it runs OnNameChange() where I raise the event.

This is where I want the "OnDispatcherNameChange" method to be run where it displays a message ("Dispatcher's name changed to ").

However, when I run the main, and enter a name, it returns a StackOverFlowException. How can I fix this?

This is my code:

```
using System;

namespace Excercise_Events
{

    public class NameChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public NameChangeEventArgs(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }
    public class Dispatcher
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return Name; 
            }
            set
            {
                var nameChange = new NameChangeEventArgs(Name);
                OnNameChange(nameChange);

                Name = value; 
            } 
        }

        public delegate void NameChangeEventHandler(object Source, NameChangeEventArgs args);

        public event NameChangeEventHandler NameChange;

        protected virtual void OnNameChange(NameChangeEventArgs args)
        {
            NameChange?.Invoke(this, new NameChangeEventArgs(args.Name));
        }

    }

    public class Handler
    {
        public void OnDispatcherNameChange(object Source, NameChangeEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dispatcher's name changed to {0}", args.Name);
        } 
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
            var handler = new Handler();

            dispatcher.NameChange += handler.OnDispatcherNameChange;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter new Name: ");
                string name = Console.ReadLine();
                if (name.ToLower() == "end")
                {
                    break; 
                }
                dispatcher.Name = name;
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we help if you don't show us your code? Have you tried debugging and stepping through your app?

Comment: Sorry, I was just entering the code. It is there now.

Comment: Look at your property getters and setters. Infinite recursion (well, it would only be truly infinite if you were to also have an infinite call stack. But since the call stack is finite, the infinite recursive eventually exhausts the call stack, causing your programa running the (attempted) infinite recursion to crash straight right into a wall at the end of the road, so to speak...)

Comment: `Dispatcher.Name.get` refers to itself, which calls itself, which calls itself, which calls itself, which calls itself, which calls itself, which calls itself..... (can you see where this is going?)

Comment: Your Name property needs a backing field. Currently when you change it you set the Name to value, which calls the setter which sets Name to value which calls the setter etc.

Comment: Also, your logic with regard to your NameChangeEvent will not quite exactly do what you seem to think it does (based on the text `"Dispatcher's name changed to {0}"` there for the Console.WriteLine call in the OnDispatcherNameChange method...)

Comment: And one more: Why does your `OnNameChange` method creates yet another new NameChangeEventArgs instance? Not really a significant mistake, but looks like you were burning the midnight oil or otherwisely absent-minded when writing this code...

Comment: I have just learnt about events so I'm quite rusty. How would you do it?

Comment: I was just pointing out some things i saw in the code in your question. If you observe unexpected behavior of your program and you don't really understand why it is showing this unexpected behavior, use Visual Studios debugger to get an understanding of what your code really does and where/how it exactly diverges from your expectations. The debugger is not only one of the most powerful and useful tools for any programmer, but it can also be an invaluable learning aid for the aspiring programmer. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) In case you are not familiar with Visual Studio's awesome debugger yet, there is a neat online guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019) teaching you about its many neat features such as how to step/walk through code, how to utilize breakpoints, how to inspect the values of variables and data in objects, and some other things more...

Comment: Also, you said that "Dispatcher's name changed to {0}" won't do exactly what I want it to. It doesn't display the name of the dispatcher on the first inputted name. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Name property is the problem. You have an infinite loop where the setter is calling the property again to set another value.

Change it to use a backing field:

```
private string _name;

public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return _name; 
    }
    set
    {
        var nameChange = new NameChangeEventArgs(Name);
        OnNameChange(nameChange);

        _name = value; 
     } 
}
```